# How do I make my unicode within span encompass full width and height of parent?

Tags: css, unicode

so basically when I press roll, I want the dice visuals that appear to span the full width and height of the span element that it is within. I also want that span element to take up 100% of its parent container div, with the class name "dice".

Here is my JS:

```
const btn=document.querySelector("button")
const player=document.querySelectorAll('.player')


player.forEach(player=> {
  diceDiv=document.createElement("div")
  span=document.createElement("span")
  player.appendChild(diceDiv)
  diceDiv.appendChild(span)
})



const diceRoll=(span)=> {
  let numOfDots = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1  
  span.innerHTML='&#9856'
}


btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  player.forEach(player=> player.firstElementChild.classList.add("dice"))
  const spans=document.querySelectorAll('span')
  spans.forEach(span=> {
    diceRoll(span)
  })
})
```

However, I tried doing this and the unicode dice face is still appearing at the bottom of my div. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

**I hope the main purpose of this game is JS and not CSS**,
After playing with your fiddle, If you add following properties to your **span** element, it would take the space of parent div i.e "dice"

```
display: inline-block;
font-size: 202px;
margin-top: -72px;
```